# Format Number with Leading & Trailing Zero

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

How can I convert `32.5` to `000003250` in Excel 2010?

I have tried `TEXT(A1,"#000000.000000")` and `=A1&REPT("0",6-LEN(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1))))`

Both examples return with decimal point notation.

Comment: If you could update your question to provide any limits to the numbers you are processing. For example, Tyson's answer multiplies by 100 to remove the decimal point, but what if one of your numbers is tiny and multiplying by 100 still gives a decimal point?

Answer (score 2):

One way is using a method you were playing with:

```
=TEXT(A1*100,"#000000000000")
```

In this case we move the decimal point out of the way first by multiplying the value by 100.